# Creating dropdown menu in django for user created data only in a different class

Tags: python, django

I'm new to programming and my first language/stack is Python and Django.  I have figured out how to create a dropdown menu in my Script form that is pointing to a different class "Patient" but I can't figure out how to only show me data that the current user created.  I'm confused if I should set this in my models.py, forms.py or in the views.py? Here is what I have that I think should be working but it is not. (Tried setting in the views.py)

**Models.py**

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    patient_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient_name

class Script(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Primary Patient')
```

So my patient field is my dropdown and it is looking at the Patient class grabbing the patient name string.  I only want patient_name entry's that this user created in the dropdown.

**Views.py**

```
class ScriptCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Script
    template_name = 'script_new.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('script_list')
    fields = (
                'patient',
                'drug_name', 
                'drug_instructions', 
                'drug_start_day', 
                'drug_start_time', 
                'drug_hours_inbetween', 
                'drug_num_days_take',
                
    )

#This sets user created fields only??
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            author=self.request.user
        )
#This sets the author ID in the form
    def form_valid(self, form): 
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form
        )
```

**Forms.py**

```
class ScriptForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Script
        fields = '__all__'

#This is requiring user login for any of these views??
    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user:
            self.fields['patient'].queryset = Patient.objects.filter(author=user)
```

I'm sure it is my lack of experience here but I thought by setting the function def get_queryset in the view that it would only show me user created data.  I have googled a bunch and I really can't find the clear answer on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the last form.fields query below in the view which filtered items only created by "author" which is what I was looking for:

```
def get_form(self):
    form = super().get_form()
    form.fields['drug_start_day'].widget = DatePickerInput()
    form.fields['drug_start_time'].widget = TimePickerInput()
    form.fields['patient'].queryset = Patient.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
    return form
```

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py file initialize form like this please

```
<form or form_class> = Form(request.POST, user=request.user)
```

Comment: I added this to the top of my views.py 
```from .forms import ScriptForm```

I added this to the ScriptCreateView
```form = ScriptForm(request.POST, user=request.user)```

I now get this error:
\views.py", line 97, in ScriptCreateView
    form = ScriptForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
NameError: name 'request' is not defined

I'm not sure how to define 'request'?

Comment: Maybe you didn't add request arg in your view.